# The !contains() Method? Is that possible?

Tags: java, regex

I know that by using contains you can check to see if a String contains certain words, or whatnots. But is there a !contains method? For example, I want it to check the string to see if it contains the word "like", but I also want it to check for if it doesn't contain the word "not". Is that possible?

```
if (text.contains("like")&&text.!contains("not")){
System.out.println("Is that a trick question? Yes.");
x = 1;}
```

Comment: Surely you just want `!text.contains("not")`?

Comment: Ah, yes that. I just wasn't sure where to place the ! mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is close. It's like this,

```
String text = "like yes";
if (text.contains("like") && !text.contains("not")) {
    System.out.println("like yes");
}
text = "like not";
if (text.contains("like") && !text.contains("not")) {
    System.out.println("like not");
}
```

Output is

```
like yes
```

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a unary operator, just like unary `-` which is used to compute the negative of a number.  To use it, you write an expression whose value is `boolean` (or `Boolean`) and put `!` in front of it; you may have to put the expression in parentheses.

`text.contains("not")` is an expression.  Specifically, it's a method call that returns a `boolean`.  And a method call that returns a value is an expression.  So to get the inverse of the expression, put `!` before it.

Sometimes you have to use parentheses to get the grouping right, such as

```
!(text.length() == 0 || text.contains("abc"))
```

which checks to see if one or the other is true, and then gives `false` if either part is true.  You could write

```
!(text.contains("not"))
```

but it's not necessary.

But the key thing to remember is that `!` is an operator and you use it like other operators.  You shouldn't be confused about where to place it if you remember that.